# Export from BigQuery to Google Cloud Datastore

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-datastore

Is there a trick to export Google BigQuery data to Google Cloud Datastore? I can read that the other way around is possible.

Comment: This feature would have been very handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no native functionality to create entities in datastore from query results.  You can certainly write code using the [API libraries](https://developers.google.com/discovery/libraries) that walks some BQ results and performs datastore inserts, however.